# How to pass a parameterized secret to a reusable GitHub Action workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-secret

I am running into an issue wherein I cannot make a part of my workflow reusable. Here is the gist of it

```yaml
deploy_app1:
  name: Deploy App1 / Production
  uses: ./.github/workflows/_deploy.yaml
  needs: validate
  if: ${{ needs.validate.outputs.deploy_app1 != 0 }}
  with:
    vercel_org_id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_APP1_ORG_ID }}
    vercel_project_id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_APP1_PROJECT_ID }}
    turbo_token: ${{ secrets.TURBO_TOKEN }}
    turbo_team: ${{ secrets.TURBO_TEAM }}
deploy_app2:
  name: Deploy App2 / Production
  uses: ./.github/workflows/_deploy.yaml
  needs: validate
  if: ${{ needs.validate.outputs.deploy_app2 != 0 }}
  with:
    vercel_org_id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_APP2_ORG_ID }}
    vercel_project_id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_APP2_PROJECT_ID }}
    turbo_token: ${{ secrets.TURBO_TOKEN }}
    turbo_team: ${{ secrets.TURBO_TEAM }}
```

As you can see, the org id and the project id can differ, while the actual steps of the reusable workflow are identical as they only differ in the input:

```yaml
name: Deploy Application
on:
  workflow_call:
    input:
      vercel_org_id:
        type: string
        required: true
      vercel_project_id:
        type: string
        required: true
      turbo_token:
        type: string
        required: true
      turbo_team:
        type: string
        required: true
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      VERCEL_ORG_ID: ${{ inputs.vercel_org_id }}
      VERCEL_PROJECT_ID: ${{ inputs.vercel_project_id }}
      TURBO_TOKEN: ${{ inputs.turbo_token }}
      TURBO_TEAM: ${{ inputs.turbo_team }}
    steps:
      - // ... do stuff ...
```

Unfortunately GitHub errors on the `with` clause at the very top when attempting to access the secrets before even passing them down:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/production.yaml (Line: 74, Col: 22): Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'. Located at position 1 within expression: secrets.VERCEL_APP1_ORG_ID
```

I couldn't find any way to solve this as all suggestions to handle secrets revolve around just sharing the same "global" secrets rather than parameterizing them.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Consider [inheriting secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow) instead of passing them one by one.

Comment: @rethab I've written that I do not want to just pass the same secrets down, but selectively parameterize them instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is related to the fact that **secrets** are considered as **a different type of inputs** in a `workflow_call` trigger configuration.

[Here is a reference from the official Github Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow)

Therefore, your reusable workflow should instead looks like this:

```yaml
name: Deploy Application
on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      vercel_org_id:
        required: true
      vercel_project_id:
        required: true
      turbo_token:
        required: true
      turbo_team:
        required: true
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      VERCEL_ORG_ID: ${{ secrets.vercel_org_id }}
      VERCEL_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.vercel_project_id }}
      TURBO_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.turbo_token }}
      TURBO_TEAM: ${{ secrets.turbo_team }}
    steps:
      - // ... do stuff ...
```

Using the **`secrets`** keyword instead of the **`inputs`** one in your reusable workflow should resolve your problem.